# Insertion sorting integers read from a file into a linked list java

Tags: java, file, sorting, integer, insertion-sort

I need to read integers in from a file into a linked list, sort the list using insertion sort, and then report how long it took my machine to complete the insertion sort using java. Currently, my code does everything right except for reading from the file, it only reads in the first and last number. For example, if I read from a file that has the numbers 1 to 5000 in reverse order it will only read and sort 5000 and one.

How can I read all integers from a file into ListNodes? Code posted below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class InsertionLinkedList {

    public static ListNode insertionSortList(ListNode head) {

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        if (head == null || head.next == null)
            return head;

        ListNode newHead = new ListNode(head.val);
        ListNode pointer = head.next;

        // loop through each element in the list
        while (pointer != null) {
            // insert this element to the new list

            ListNode innerPointer = newHead;
            ListNode next = pointer.next;

            if (pointer.val <= newHead.val) {
                ListNode oldHead = newHead;
                newHead = pointer;
                newHead.next = oldHead;
            } else {
                while (innerPointer.next != null) {

                    if (pointer.val > innerPointer.val && pointer.val <= innerPointer.next.val) {
                        ListNode oldNext = innerPointer.next;
                        innerPointer.next = pointer;
                        pointer.next = oldNext;
                    }

                    innerPointer = innerPointer.next;
                }

                if (innerPointer.next == null && pointer.val > innerPointer.val) {
                    innerPointer.next = pointer;
                    pointer.next = null;
                }
            }

            // finally
            pointer = next;
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("The time taken was %.1f ns%n", (double) time);
        return newHead;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("random5k.txt"));
        ListNode insertion = new ListNode(scanner.nextInt());
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            ListNode nextNode = new ListNode(scanner.nextInt());
            insertion.next = nextNode;
        }

        insertion = insertionSortList(insertion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: I fixed my question to match those dos and dont's.

Comment: That's better, however, it looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Currently, my code does everything right except for reading from the
>   file, it only reads in the first and last number. For example, if I
>   read from a file that has the numbers 1 to 5000 in reverse order it
>   will only read and sort 5000 and one.

You are actually reading all the numbers from the file correctly. It is just that when you try to populate the `ListNode` object `insertion`, you do not point the `next` of each node to the actual next node. See my edits in your program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("random5k.txt"));
ListNode insertion = new ListNode(scanner.nextInt());
ListNode intNodes = insertion;
while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    ListNode nextNode = new ListNode(scanner.nextInt());
    insertion.next = nextNode;
    insertion = nextNode;
}
intNodes = insertionSortList(intNodes);
}
```

Comment: The question requires sorting, and your answer doesn't accomplish it. It also fails on empty lists.

Comment: @EJP, apologies. I tried to provide an answer before even reading the full question. I have edited my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please take care of the negative vote on this answer?

Comment: I unfortunately can't because my reputation is lower than 15.

Comment: Oh I see. No problem.